# Redis - linux / Error when Installing redis on linux: `cc: command not found`

Tags: linux, redis

I wish to install redis on my red-hat environment. I do the following:

```
wget http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
tar xvzf redis-stable.tar.gz
cd redis-stable
make
```

I got the next error:

```
make[3]: *** [net.o] Error 127
make[3]: Leaving directory `/tmp/redis-stable/deps/hiredis'
make[2]: *** [hiredis] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/redis-stable/deps'
make[1]: [persist-settings] Error 2 (ignored)
    CC adlist.o
/bin/sh: cc: command not found
make[1]: *** [adlist.o] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/redis-stable/src'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You are trying to install `redis` from source code. What this process do is to compile and create executable on your machine and then install it. For doing this you need various tools like `gcc` etc. Best way is to install all of them together by installing that group. Run this from terminal

```
yum grouplist
```

This will show all groups available and then choose group you want to install or run directly

```
yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
```

This will save you from other problems which might come in future while installing from source.

Comment: It gives me the following error: `Setting up Group Process
Warning: Group Development Tools does not exist.
No packages in any requested group available to install or update`

Comment: @MiddleWare are you able to run this `yum install gcc`.

Comment: It gives the following error: `Setting up Install Process
No package gcc available.
Error: Nothing to do`

Comment: You have some issue with your repo then. What is the output of `yum repolist` .

Comment: I have the following line: `rhel-source                                                    Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6Server - x86_64 - Source                                                    enabled:   0`

Comment: You do not have any repository set in your machine. First add a repo and then only these things will work

Comment: Which repo should I add?

Comment: @MiddleWare sorry for late reply. I think you should install `epel` repository on your machine. This will consist of all packages(mostly) and will solve your problem. Simple google will help you in installing.

Comment: If you want to be minimalist: for Redis (as of 5.0.3), `yum install gcc` is sufficient for the `make` and `yum install tcl` is sufficient for the `make test`

Answer (score 16):

for those of you who encounter this error

[check this github issue](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/722)

before make run this command

```
$ cd deps; make hiredis lua jemalloc linenoise
```

Comment: Please, add the error log to the post, don't redirect us using a link.

Comment: what are you talking about ? i stated the command as an answer. just run the command before `make`

Comment: In my case, I also needed `geohash-int`

Answer (score 5):

Install build essential first

> sudo apt-get install build-essential

then install the dependencies

> cd deps
>
> make hiredis lua jemalloc linenoise

Answer (score 3):

If you're not an advanced user maybe it is not a good idea to install REDIS from the source.

Instead you should install a packaged version. For example on Fedora / Centos / RHEL:

```
sudo yum install redis
```

Comment: Underestimated advice !

Answer (score 0):

Come out from your extracted `folder/Dir` and  remove the extracted `redis-x.x.x` folder with `rm -rf redis-x.x.x`

now again extract the `redis` folder with `tar xzf redis-x.x.x.tar.gz`

go to `redis directory` again and run the make or make test again. it works for me.

Comment: It would be great if you provide minimal code for all of us, so that it could be better to reproduce on any OS. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, working with ubi8/ubi-minimal. The `make` command kept failing until I installed `gcc` as well:

```
RUN microdnf -y update \
    && microdnf install -y tar.x86_64 gzip bash make bind-utils gcc  \
    && microdnf clean all
```

If you look at the [redis Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/redis/blob/b77450d34ae54354f41970fc44bf840353f59ef4/7.2/debian/Dockerfile), you will see that it is used there as well.